# Rails File Upload with Nested Attribute, "file_content" is blank when file gets saved

Tags: file-upload, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-attributes

I've been following this tutorial to upload file to db [Rails File Upload](http://ryan.endacott.me/2014/06/10/rails-file-upload.html)
.

The problem is `file_contents` field is blank when file gets saved and I'm uploading file with `nested_attributes`.

**subject.rb**   *//model*

```
class Subject < ApplicationRecord
  has_many  :documents
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :documents
end
```

**document.rb**   *//model*

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :subject

def initialize(params = {})
  @file = params.delete(:file)
  super
  if @file
    self.filename = sanitize_filename(@file.original_filename)
    self.content_type = @file.content_type
    self.file_contents = @file.read
  end
end

private

  def sanitize_filename(filename)
    return File.basename(filename)
  end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**   //view

```
<%=  form_for(subject) do |f| %>
.......
   <div class="uk-form-row">
      <%= f.fields_for :documents do |d| %>
         <%= d.file_field :file, class:"uk-width-1-1 uk-form-large", placeholder:"upload document" %>
      <% end %>
   </div>
............
<% end %>
```

**subjects_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @subject = Subject.new
  @subject.documents.build
end

def create
  @subject = Subject.new(subject_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @subject.save
      format.html { redirect_to @subject, notice: 'Lesson was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end

private
  def subject_params
    params.require(:subject).permit(:title, documents_attributes:[:file])
  end
```

Am I in the right way ? What am I missing ? I need your thoughts.

Thanks,

Comment: You talk about a `file_content` field, but in your code appears a `file` field. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @AlterLagos i think that's not a problem since uploading a file without `nested_attributes` gives me no problem. BTW I updated my `document.rb`